# Qt QDialog moves location slightly each time it is closed and showed again

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have a QDialog and it pops up as a top level window in the center of my main window the first time it is opened(great, exactly what I want). However, each time I hit the "X" to close the window, when I trigger an event to cause the QDialog to pop up again(I use show() function for this)...the widget has slightly moved down and to the right(maybe 10 pixels each way, each time). Does anyone know what is causing this behavior/have a solution? Ideally I would like it to always pop up in the center of my main window(like it does the first time it opens).

Thanks in advance.

```
commandTimeWindow = new QDialog();
commandTimeWindow->resize(390, 180);
commandTimeWindow->setWindowTitle("Command In Progress");
commandTimeWindow->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
commandTimeWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowTitleHint |     Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
commandTimeWindow->setWindowIcon(QIcon(""));
commandTimeWindow->installEventFilter(this);


 commandTimeWindow->close();

 commandTimeWindow->show();
```

Also the standard "X" button closes the window...but I didnt write any code on this end.

Comment: Make it center all the time? You want to learn how?

Comment: Please provide code how you show/hide this dialog and showEvent/hideEvent functions if you have, maybe constructor. So watever you feel is relevant. Then it will be much easier to help you

Comment: Yes please. It has to always center on the main window though, just not on the screen. So if I have two monitors, I want it to still center on the main window of the application no matter which monitor it is on.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? It's a known bug (search on the bugtracker).

Comment: 5.3.1 with MS VS2010 compiler

Comment: I have added some more code with how I am constructing it.

Comment: Same bug without `setWindowFlags` nor `installEventFilter`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the widget's move(x, y) method or replace resize with setGeometry.

Comment: If I use move(), the only way i know how is to center it on the screen, not the mainwindow itself. If you know how to do it on the main window itself could you please provide an example?

Comment: Well, mainwindow->pos() will return the top left corner location on screen as QPoint, so you could do something like
QPoint mainPos = mainwindow->pos();
commandWindow->move(mainPos.x() + x, mainPos.y() + y);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue using the code below:

```
void MyMainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event)
{
    const QPoint global = this->mapToGlobal(rect().center());
    waitDialog->move(global.x() - waitDialog->width() / 2, global.y() -   waitDialog->height() / 2);
}
```